# How to fetch blob from azure

Tags: azure, go, azure-sdk-for-go

I am trying to download some data from Azure Blob Storage in Go via the official `azure-sdk-for-go`.

To setup my development environment I have successfully logged in via `az login`. I have verified that the blob can be accessed via CLI:

```
az storage blob download --container-name [container-name] --name [blob-name] --account-name [storage-account-name] -f out.txt
```

This works as expected. To fetch the file unsing go I am using the following snippet (as a reproducer):

```golang
func getBlob(account, container, object string) ([]byte, error) {
        blobPath := fmt.Sprintf("https://%s.blob.core.windows.net/%s/%s", uri.Host, container, object)
        ctx := context.Background()

        credential, err := azidentity.NewDefaultAzureCredential(nil)
        if err != nil {
            return []byte{}, err
        }

        blobClient, err := azblob.NewBlockBlobClient(blobPath, credential, nil)
        if err != nil {
            return []byte{}, err
        }

        get, err := blobClient.Download(ctx, nil)
        if err != nil {
            return []byte{}, err
        }

        downloadedData := &bytes.Buffer{}
        reader := get.Body(&azblob.RetryReaderOptions{})
        _, err = downloadedData.ReadFrom(reader)
        if err != nil {
            return []byte{}, err
        }
        err = reader.Close()
        if err != nil {
            return []byte{}, err
        }
        data = downloadedData.Bytes()
        return data, nil
}
```

Being logged in via `az login` I would expect `azidentity.NewDefaultAzureCredential(nil)` to use this session/cerdentials (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/go/azure-sdk-authentication?tabs=bash#-option-3-sign-in-with-azure-cli), however that appears not no work as expected. The error I get is the following:

```
===== RESPONSE ERROR (ErrorCode=AuthorizationPermissionMismatch) =====
Description=This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
RequestId:b078ec61-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-604682000000
Time:2022-05-05T10:24:18.8093649Z, Details: (none)

exit status 255
```

What am I missing?

(I am coming from a AWS background so chances are I am making assumptions on how things should work based on that experience.)

Comment: It might be similar issues: [Use a token to connect to a container](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/issues/16792) and [Blob service returns undocumented error AuthorizationPermissionMismatch](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go/issues/183)

Comment: [Getting started - Managing Compute using Azure Golang SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/pull/17763#issuecomment-1118098986)

Comment: DeepDave-MT Thanks for pointing out. According to the discussion in the issue you have linked the problem are apparently rooted in the permissions. 

In my case the access apparently works using the `az` CLI. With the same permissions (I am working as owner) I would expect my go code to work, at least from a permission perspective. However chances are that `azidentity.NewDefaultAzureCredential(nil)` is not reusing the credentials from `az login` in the manner I currently assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently interacting with blobs does not work with credentials provided by `azidentity.NewDefaultAzureCredential()`. Azure requires either SAS Tokens or Shared Keys in order to work with blobs. Here's an example function that can be used to get a client for specific blob:

```golang
func getBlobClient(account, container, object string) (*azblob.BlockBlobClient, error) {
    accountKey, ok := os.LookupEnv("AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY")
    if !ok {
        return nil, errors.New("AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY could not be found")
    }

    credential, err := azblob.NewSharedKeyCredential(account, accountKey)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    accountPath := fmt.Sprintf("https://%s.blob.core.windows.net/", account)
    serviceClient, err := azblob.NewServiceClientWithSharedKey(accountPath, credential, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    containerClient, err := serviceClient.NewContainerClient(container)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    blobClient, err := containerClient.NewBlockBlobClient(object)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return blobClient, nil
}
```

This uses the `AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY` environment variable for the credentials.

The examples that can be found are rather confusing (and possibly wrong), an issue is opened here:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blobs-go-quickstart/issues/7